# Fetching records from multiple tables logically with SQLServer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem with fetching the records.
Finding it too difficult to get tis but though I am trying. 
Please help me regarding this::
Actually My requirement is to get  that records from table1 whose sender and reciever userid =5 and to that corresponding records if the pkId of the selected result exists in 
table2 as fkid and have to check userId again in table2 with Isdeleted=false

I want to get records from table1 only where sender=5 or receiver=5
and then I need to check the pkId of table1 if it exists in 
table2 as fkId then idDeleted should be false but 
while checking from table2, I am having a condition to search only where
  table2.userid =5

I have tried this but not working

```
 select distinct pkId ,  Message,  data  from  table1
      left outer join  table2 on 
    table2.fkId =table1.pkMessageId
    where ((table1.sender ='5' or  table1.receiver='5' )
    or table2.userid='5') and table2.isDeleted=0

table1
pkId     sender       receiver      Message    data         date

1            2                  5                 M1              D1           blah_Blah
2            2                  5                 M2              D2          blah_Blah
3            5                  7                 M3              D3          blah_Blah
4            5                  2                 M4              D4          blah_Blah
5            5                  2                 M5              D4          blah_Blah
table2
Id         fkId             userid             isDeleted

1          1                    5                    true
2          1                    5                    false
3          2                    5                   false
4          2                     2                  false
5          3                    2                   false
6          4                    2                   true
7          1                    2                   true
8          2                   2                    false
```

Comment: Is this Oracle or SQL Server? It's unlikely to be both. Can you put your requirements in point form and try to format your sample data?

Comment: What exactly is not working? can you show expected result?

Comment: Removed the [linq] tag. If you want something with linq, please give more details.

Comment: I don't see a column `table1.pkMessageId` so I would swap that for `pkId` and then remove the `distinct` keyword from the `select`

Comment: I think your issue is you are using the same table for `sender` and `receiver`, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select distinct pkId ,  Message,  data  from  table1
Where (sender = 5 Or receiver = 5) and pkId in
(
   Select fkid From table 
   Where isDeleted=0
)
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ it answers the question rather than just dumping some code without an explanation , which doesn't make this a very useful question/answer for the future.

Comment: Please check my question . I have edited my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you are using the same table for `sender` and `receiver` you need to join to the same table twice...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 Sender
ON Table1.Sender = Sender.userid
INNER JOIN Table2 Receiver
ON Table1.Receiver = Receiver.userid
WHERE
    Receiver.isDeleted = 0
AND
    Sender.isDeleted = 0
AND
( 
    Receiver.userid = 5
    OR 
    Sender.userid = 5
)
```

from your description what you are saying is

```
SELECT 
    T1.* 
FROM 
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 T2
ON 
    T1.pkId = T2.fkId
WHERE 
    (T1.Sender = 5 OR T1.Receiver = 5)
AND
    T2.isDeleted = 0
AND 
    T2.userid = 5
```

Comment: Please check my question I have updated my requirement

Comment: @Sweetie See my second example, this is the SQL representation of what you have described

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid the distinct with an `EXISTS` statement:

```
select pkId, Message, data 
from  table1
where exists ( select 1
               from table2 
               where table2.fkId = table1.pkMessageId
               and table2.isDeleted=0
               and table2.userid='5' )
and   (sender ='5' or  receiver='5' )
```

This is assuming a few things though:

- table2.fkId = table1.pkMessageId is the right way of joining the two tables (pkMessageId is lacking in your example data)
- You do not want table1.sender ='5' or  table1.receiver='5' or table2.userid='5'

If you want OR, OR, OR, this could be what you are looking for:

```
select pkId, Message, data 
from  table1
where exists ( select 1
               from table2 
               where table2.fkId = table1.pkMessageId
               and table2.isDeleted = 0
               and table2.userid='5' )
or    sender ='5'
or    receiver='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go step by step through your new version of your requirements:

> Actually My requirement is to get that records from table1 whose sender and reciever userid =5 and to that corresponding records if the pkId of the selected result exists in table2 as fkid and have to check userId again in table2 with Isdeleted=false

I'll take this step by step.

> records from table1 whose sender and reciever userid =5

That is easy, in your example data, there are no such records. 
Now, I will assume you mean

> records from table1 whose sender OR reciever userid =5

So that leads to a first part of our query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 t1
 WHERE t1.sender = 5
    OR t1.receiver = 5
```

Then, we go further:

> and to that corresponding records if the pkId of the selected result exists in table2 as fkid

So, we *LEFT JOIN* table 2 on matching keys:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.pkID = t2.fkId
    WHERE t1.sender = 5
       OR t1.receiver = 5
```

Almost there:

> and have to check userId again in table2 with Isdeleted=false

I am *assuming* you want to only add the extra data from table2 if this condition is met, but is the condition is not met, you still want the data from table1. To acheive this, I will put this condition in the JOIN condition, rather than in th eWHERE clause. In the where clause, if the condition is not met, the whole record will be removed, not just the data from table2.

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.pkID = t2.fkId
                   AND t2.IsDeleted = 0
    WHERE t1.sender = 5 
       OR t1.receiver = 5
```

Now, this looks a lot like what you already had created, but I would not know why it would not give you the desired result. So if this does not give you the desired or expected result, please tell us what is going wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

```
--Try Like This..
SELECT * FROM Table1
Where ( Sender = 5  
OR Reciever = 5 )
AND PKID  in ( Select FKID From Table2 Where IsDeleted = 0)

-- It would be easy if u can provide the table structures also...
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ it answers the question rather than just dumping some code without an explanation , which doesn't make this a very useful question/answer for the future.